# Ler ficheiros Numpy no Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, numpy, load

Boa tarde, estou neste momento a desenvolver um projeto de Inteligência Artificial. Na fase atual do meu projeto, tenho as minhas redes neuronais implementadas e estou na fase de treinar a rede neuronal. Inicialmente, comecei por treinar a rede no meu computador, mas entretanto obtive acesso a um servidor que me permite treinar a rede com recurso ao Jupyter Lab (que me permite agilizar o processo de treino). 
O problema é que ao ler alguns ficheiros Numpy, aparece-me erros de encoding, tal como este:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 236, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 789, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 975, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/home/jfm-castilho/Chargrid/dataset_generator.py", line 26, in __getitem__
    batch_x.append(np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True,encoding = 'latin1'))

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 428, in load
    fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_13003]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

No meu computador, não ocorre nenhum problema ao ler os ficheiros Numpy, apenas quando tento ler os ficheiros através do Jupyter Lab. Como posso corrigir este erro. A linha no qual aparece o erro é a primeira linha do excerto de código em cima.

Algumas considerações:

- A versão do Numpy é igual tanto no computador como no Jupyter Lab: 1.18.1
- Os ficheiros lidos pelo computador e pelo JupyterLab são os mesmos (Fiz upload dos ficheiros para o servidor onde está situado o JupyterLab e o Relative Path onde estão situados os ficheiros é o mesmo tanto no computador como no JupyterLab.)
- Já testei diversas abordagens para resolver o problema, tais como:

  - `np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True,encoding = 'bytes')`
  - `np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True,encoding = 'ascii')`
  - `np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True,encoding = 'utf-8')`
  - `np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True)`
  - `with open(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", 'rb') as file:
      arr = pickle.load(file)`

Em nenhuma destas tentativas o resultado foi diferente, originando em todos os casos um UnicodeEncodeError.

Não sei se ajuda na análise, a linha onde guardo o NumPy Array num Numpy File é a seguinte:

```
np.save(repr_path_pad + simple_img_name[idx], data_padded)
```

---

Esta é a classe onde leio os ficheiros, é um generator que é utilizado ao treinar a rede neuronal. O batch size é igual 7, pelo que ele lê 7 ficheiros de cada vez.

```
class RepresentationGenerator(Sequence):

def __init__(self, representation_path, target_path, filenames, batch_size):
    self.filenames = np.array(filenames)
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.representation_path = representation_path
    self.target_path = target_path

def __len__(self):
    length = len(self.filenames) // self.batch_size
    if len(self.filenames) % self.batch_size > 0:
        length += 1

    return length

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    files_to_batch = self.filenames[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_x = []
    batch_SS = []
    for file in files_to_batch:
        batch_x.append(np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True))
        batch_SS.append(np.load(self.target_path + 'semantic segmentation/' + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True))
    batch_x = np.array(batch_x).astype(np.float16)
    batch_SS = np.array(batch_SS).astype(np.float16)

    return batch_x, batch_SS
```

---

Em baixo, deixo o excerto de código onde a classe acima é chamada

```
train_generator = RepresentationGenerator(representation_path=repr_path_pad, target_path=target_path_pad,
                                              filenames=training_filenames, batch_size=self.batch_size)
val_generator = RepresentationGenerator(representation_path=representations_path, target_path=target_path,
                                            filenames=validation_filenames, batch_size=self.batch_size)
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_name + '.h5',
                                                     save_weights_only=True,
                                                     verbose=1)
plot_history = PlotHistory(history_fit, model_name, self.model, model_path=model_path,
                               load_previous=load_previous)
self.model.fit(train_generator,
               steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
               verbose=1,
               epochs=num_epochs_train,
               validation_data=val_generator,
               validation_steps=len(val_generator),
               callbacks=[cp_callback, plot_history]
```

### )

---

Em baixo, deixo o log de erro completo

```
-
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9a8acfabebd2> in <module>
    212          split_dataset_file=split_dataset, ocr_filename=ocr_file, annotated_filename=annotated_files,
    213          num_epochs_trainning=num_epochs_train, history_fit=history_fit_image, width_padding=w_padding,
--> 214          upsample_path=original_repr_path, upsample_target_path=original_target_path)

<ipython-input-1-9a8acfabebd2> in main(images_path, representation_path, targets_path, repr_pad_path, target_padded_path, prefix, make_new_representation, train, use_previous_weights, split_dataset_file, model_filename, model_path, downsample, ocr_filename, annotated_filename, num_epochs_trainning, history_fit, width_padding, predict, upsample_path, upsample_target_path, update_dicts, num_chars)
     94                  split_dataset=split_dataset_file,
     95                  validation_filenames=data['val_imgs'], history_fit=history_fit,
---> 96                  model_name=model_filename, num_epochs_train=num_epochs_trainning)
     97     if predict:  # if want to predict
     98         if not train:  # if neural network wasn't trained, load model

~/Chargrid/neural_network.py in train(self, representations_path, target_path, repr_path_pad, target_path_pad, training_filenames, validation_filenames, model_path, model_name, num_epochs_train, history_fit, split_dataset, batch_size)
     85                            epochs=num_epochs_train,
     86                            validation_data=val_generator,
---> 87                            validation_steps=len(val_generator)
     88                            )
     89         except KeyboardInterrupt:

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    341                 training_context=training_context,
--> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
    343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    344 

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    127       try:
--> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     99 
    100   return execution_function

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    597       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    598       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 599       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    600     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    601       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2361     with self._lock:
   2362       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2363     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2364 
   2365   @property

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1609          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1610                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1611         self.captured_inputs)
   1612 
   1613   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1690       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1691       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1692           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1693     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1694         args,

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543               inputs=args,
    544               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 545               ctx=ctx)
    546         else:
    547           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 236, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 789, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 975, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/home/jfm-castilho/Chargrid/dataset_generator.py", line 26, in __getitem__
    batch_x.append(np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True,encoding = 'latin1'))

  File "/opt/conda/envs/csw-aii/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 428, in load
    fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_13003]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Comment: A codificação do seu arquivo de entrada é mesmo `LATIN1`  ? Já tentou usar o `encoding="utf-8"` ?

Comment: Como posso saber qual é a codificação, não passo essa informação quando faço save do Numpy Array no ficheiro. Nunca considerei o 'utf-8, pois na documentação do Numpy diz que não devem ser considerados encodings que não sejam 'ASCII', 'latin1', ou 'bytes'

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.load.html?highlight=load#numpy.load

Comment: Testei agora com 'utf-8' e o voltou a dar o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde!

Acredito que o erro seja decorrente a tentativa de alocação muito alta de memória por parte da operação em questão, o Jupiter Lab é um ambiente para desenvolvimento compartilhado, logo não possui o mesmo nível de disponibilidade de hardware.

Para poder lhe ajudar mais, precisamos saber oque você esta tentando executar dando esse batch_x.append, pois, somente saber que se você esta chamando essa função não nos traz um levantamento dos possíveis erros.

Estarei aguardando por mais informações.

---

Acredito que seu problema seja a maneira que você esta tratando as informações, para poder lhe ajudar de maneira correta preciso de mais informações, como acredito que pouco provavelmente você ira disponibilizar eu irei demonstrar a baixo como eu trato os dados de uma rede neural (no caso uma CNN), talvez isso lhe ajude.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# abra os arquivos com os dados
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

train = pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("../input/test.csv")

Y_train = train["label"]
X_train = train.drop(labels = ["label"], axis = 1) 


(x_train1, y_train1), (x_test1, y_test1) = mnist.load_data()

train1 = np.concatenate([x_train1, x_test1], axis=0)
y_train1 = np.concatenate([y_train1, y_test1], axis=0)

Y_train1 = y_train1
X_train1 = train1.reshape(-1, 28*28)

X_train = X_train / 255.0
test = test / 255.0

X_train1 = X_train1 / 255.0

X_train = np.concatenate((X_train.values, X_train1))
Y_train = np.concatenate((Y_train, Y_train1))

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
test = test.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)

Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes = 10)

X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size = 0.1, random_state=2)

#Insira aqui seu Modelo de CNN e depois compile o mesmo

# Codigo a baixo previne o overfitting, em grandes volumes de dados (no caso imagens)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=10,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        zoom_range = 0.1, # Randomly zoom image 
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images


datagen.fit(X_train)

epochs = 50

batch_size = 128

callbacks = [
    TerminateOnNaN(),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', 
                      patience=5, 
                      verbose=1, 
                      factor=0.5, 
                      min_lr=0.00001),
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                 patience=5,
                 mode='min',
                 verbose=1,
                 restore_best_weights=True),
    ModelCheckpoint(h5_path,
                   monitor='val_loss',
                   verbose=1,
                   save_best_only=True,
                   mode='min')
]

history = model.fit_generator((x_train, y_train),
validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
verbose=1,
steps_per_epoch=(x_train.shape[0] // batch_size),
epochs=epochs,
callbacks=callbacks)

# Plota a a validacao da rede anteriormente treinada
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].plot(history.history['loss'], color='b', label="Training loss")
ax[0].plot(history.history['val_loss'], color='r', label="validation loss",axes=ax[0])
legend = ax[0].legend(loc='best', shadow=True)

ax[1].plot(history.history['accuracy'], color='b', label="Training accuracy")
ax[1].plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], color='r',label="Validation accuracy")
legend=ax[1].legend(loc='best', shadow=True)
```

Gostaria de deixar um adendo, caso esteja trabalhando puramente com dados como, por exemplo, valores de acoes, preço de casas, etc, tente aplicar um método estatístico provavelmente tera um resultado muito mais eficiente do que um modelo de rede neural. Espero que eu tenha conseguido lhe ajudar ao menos um pouco.

---

@JoãoCastilho agora as coisas ficaram um pouco mais claras, você esta tentando extrair um dado ou textos de um arquivo, fazendo ele fazer uma leitura como se fosse uma imagem correto? (caso esteja errado me corrija por favor)

Oque eu estou conseguindo entender pelo erro e pelo contexto, seu algorítimo de treino esta pegando as imagens (arquivos) lendo eles e fazendo a operação corretamente, entretanto, quando ele encontra o "ç" ele da erro, esse erro se decorre pelo fato da leitura estar sendo feita em um encode de padrão americano, eu lhe recomendaria utilizar o Teserract, usando ele você iria extrair os dados de texto e depois processaria a informação, ou pode tentar substituir o mesmo por outro carácter, ou pode tentar forcar a leitura do arquivo como 'latin-1' usando o código a baixo.

```py
batch_x.append(np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True, encoding='latin-1'))
batch_SS.append(np.load(self.target_path + 'semantic segmentation/' + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True, encoding='latin-1'))
```

Obs.: provavelmente a maquina onde se encontra o Jupiter esta em ingles como idioma padrao e seu computador em pt, inerente a isso existe o erro em um e o outro não.

Comment: Obrigado pela disponibilidade :) Atualizei o post com nova informação

Comment: @JoãoCastilho Atualizei minha resposta, espero que apos ler a mesma consiga resolver seu problema.

Comment: Boas, também estou a treinar uma CNN, mas não é com imagens. O que eu utilizo como input para a CNN é uma representação de uma grelha de caracteres de uma imagem, baseado no artigo https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.08799.pdf. Tive em conta o seu feedback de excesso de memória e diminui o batch size e os steps por epoch para o valor 1. E mesmo assim continua dando erro. O erro não aparece logo no início do treino, aparece a meio, pelo que acho que o problema possa não ser de leitura e sim de memória. Ainda assim, não consegui descobrir o problema. Saliento que no meu computador funciona  corretamente

Comment: atualizei o post com o log completo do erro que me aparece.

Comment: vou dar um exemplo prático. Tenho uma imagem de tamanho (255,355). O que faço na fase de pré-processamento é criar uma matriz de zeros (255,355) e no pixel onde se situa um caracter atribui-lhe um valor unico (um valor unico para cada caracter diferente). No final faço um 1-hot-encoded dessa matriz ficando com um tamanho (255,355,50) [se considerar apenas 50 caracteres] e gravo num ficheiro. Quando estou a treinar o modelo, ele lê essa matriz (255,355,50).

Comment: @JoãoCastilho eu sem querer postei oq eu estava escrevendo, por favor leia novamente minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, mas não creio que esse seja o problema. Na matriz que eu submeto na rede neuronal não estão presentes caracteres, mas sim um encoding desses caracteres (por exemplo, o 'a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2, 'ç' -> 34) pelo que nessa matriz, apenas estão contidos números.

Comment: O pré-processamento é efetuado no meu computador, no JupyterLab apenas leio os ficheiros da representação